# The Hairy Ball Theorem and $RP(2)$

Tags: general-topology

The Hairy Ball Theorem says, in particular, that there does not exist a continuous nonvanishing tangent vector field on $S^2$.  My question is whether passing to $RP(2)$ avoids this problem. Specifically:

Let $\sim$ be a lift from $RP(2)$ to $S^2$ (I actually do not know why such a lift exists; as an aside, if someone could explain, I would be very grateful!).  Does there exist a map

$g \colon RP(2) \to RP(2)$

such that if $x \in RP(2)$, then $\sim g(x)$ is perpendicular to $\sim x$?

Comment: I think I pretty much have the answer if someone can explain why a lift from $RP(2)$ to $S^2$ exists.

Comment: Do you know about Euler characteristic and it's relation to number of zeroes if a vector field?

Comment: I just kind of figured that out; Poincaré-Hopf Theorem. So since the Euler characteristic of RP2 is 1, there is no nonvanishing vector field on RP2. Does this imply that the answer to my question is in the negative? That seems to be what people are saying, but I am having trouble seeing exactly why.

Comment: If anything someone answered on a related question that no such lift exists, so this question is really ill-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is ill-defined because there does not exist a lift from $RP2$ to $S^2$ as assumed in the hypotheses.

See 
[Why does there exist a lift from $RP(2)$ to $S^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807381/why-does-there-exist-a-lift-from-rp2-to-s2/807385#807385)

As a remark then, this question is related to the fact that since the Euler characteristic of $RP2$ is 1, every vector field on $RP2$ must have exactly one isolated zero.  It is my guess that this would then answer in the negative any attempt to reformulate my question above.