# Why does there exist a lift from $RP(2)$ to $S^2$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $p$ be the quotient map from $S^2$ to $RP(2)$. I am looking for a proof that there exists a map

$g \colon RP(2) \to S^2$

such that

$p(g(x)) = x$ for all $x \in RP(2)$.

Comment: The number of regular zeroes of a vector field on a compact manifold is equivalent to its Euler characteristic mod 2. Since the Euler characteristic of the projective plane is one it has no nonvanishing vectorfield.

Comment: Hi @Charlie! Long time! How does nontrivial tangent bundle address the lifting problem?

Comment: Ted, check out the question he asked just before this one. It's been 30 years I think.

Comment: Hi Charlie, a lot of this is beyond my current knowledge and will require me fleshing stuff out, but are you saying that the answer to my other question is also in the negative?

Comment: Oh, well I see I missed the part of the wiki that gives the answer to that... So the Poincaré-Hopf Theorem says that every vector field on RP2 has at least 1 zero (and exactly one if all zeroes are isolated).  What is this business with "mod2" though? I didn't see anything mentioning that on wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There doesn't . As the quotient map is a covering projection and the spaces are Hausdorff and locally path connected, there is a lift if and only if the image of the fundamental group of RP(2) under the identity $Z_2$ is a subgroup of the image of the fundamental group of $S^2$ which is trivial.

Comment: Dan, there is this great book I read on my own when I was a first year graduate student by Guillemin and Pollack called Differential topology. They prove a bunch of classical theorems like this one and develop intersection theory. The mod2 refers to unoriented intersection theory. Charlie

Comment: Hi Charlie! I have also been told that is a great book. I will have to get to it soon!

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is essentially equivalent to Charlie's excellent answer, but perhaps provides an alternative perspective:

Note that this follows from the functoriality of the fundamental group. If $g:\mathbb{RP}^2\to \mathbb{S}^2$ existed with the stated property, then $(p\circ g)_{\ast}$ would be the identity on the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$ yet $p_{\ast}\circ g_{\ast}$ would be $0$ (since it factors through the fundamental group of $\mathbb{S}^2$, which is trivial). Finally, the identity on the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$ is non-zero since the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$ is non-zero. Q.E.D.

Note also that this is, in some sense, analogous to the non-existence of an extension of the identity $i:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1$ to a map $\mathbb{D}^2\to \mathbb{S}^1$ (or, at least the proof is).

I hope this helps!

Comment: What do you mean by " ..the identity of the fundamental group of $\mathbb RP^2$ is non-trivial ?

Comment: Dear @Name, oh by that I just meant that it is not the trivial group homomorphism (and this is true since the fundamental group of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is non-trivial).